# Are there any EU/EASA regulations surrounding aviation software?

Tags: easa-regulations, software

A great question's been asked: [Is there any U.S. / FAA regulation that could apply for aviation software?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/is-there-any-u-s-faa-regulation-that-could-apply-for-aviation-software)

This is interesting to me as a programmer and aviation enthusiast, but being based in the UK,  I'd like to know if there any *EASA* regulations surrounding the creation of software for use in the aviation industry?

Comment: I think you should specify which branch of aviation you mean. For example I work in company which develop software for airline. Single airline has many departments and each of it works on different regulations (operations, ground handling, scheduling, continuing airworthiness etc). You may also mean A/C installed equipment software.
There is no simple answer on whether there are regulations for aviations software or not. It depends on aviation branch.

Answer (score 4):

If we speak about **airborne** software, the main document is the RTCA/EUROCAE [DO-178/ED-12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C) currently at the "C" version: `Software Considerations in Airborne Systems and Equipment Certification`: if you want to certify (and thus commercialize) your software for flight, this is the main document to read.

Depending on the scope of the software and the design/development process there might be different supplements (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DO-178C#Differences_with_DO-178B)):

> - DO-330 `Software Tool Qualification Considerations`
> - DO-331 `Model-Based Development and Verification Supplement to DO-178C and DO-278`
> - DO-332 `Object-Oriented Technology and Related Techniques Supplement to DO-178C and DO-278A`
> - DO-333 `Formal Methods Supplement to DO-178C and DO-278A`

It has been prepared by the RTCA/EUROCAE joint committee and approved by both FAA and EASA under different names, but the content is the same.

As @Greg mentions, these documents are [not freely](http://www.rtca.org/store_list.asp) available

Comment: The DO and ED documents you refer to are RTCA resp. EUROCAE documents, not FAA/EASA. Also they are standards, not regulations.

Comment: @DeltaLima I say that are the "main document to read". Also they are not coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

Two relevant standards from [EUROCAE (European Organisation for Civil Aviation Equipment)](https://www.eurocae.net) are:

- ED-109A / Guidelines for CNS/ATM Systems Software Integrity Assurance
- ED-153 / Guidelines for ANS Software Safety Assurance

Unfortunately these documents are not freely available. However, you can find some information about the contents of these documents from other sites, such as [LDRA](http://www.ldra.com/index.php/en/solutions/by-standard-adherence/do-278).

Comment: These are standards, not regulations.

Answer (score 1):

EASA has published a memorandum with guidance on how to comply with the certification requirements. It is based on EUROCAE ED-12B/RTCA DO-178B, but is more specific.

It is called *EASA CM - SWCEH – 002* and you can find it [here](http://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/certification-docs-certification-memorandum-EASA-CM-SWCEH-002-Issue-01-Rev-01-Software-Aspects-of-Certification.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If you asked about the **regulation** my answer would be FAR25 25.1301 and 25.1309 for large aircraft software. DO-178C is recommended as a **means of compliance** by AC20-115D. Software review and approval guidline can refere to FAA Order8110.49 A and EASA CM-CEHSW-002.