# What physical hardware does all the avionics on the B737NG run on? Some processor from the 1980s? Or some new and improved chip?

Tags: boeing-737, avionics

So, I am a tech guy and likes to fly (in sims) so, I was wondering what physical hardware powers all the 737NG's avionics and related systems (PFD, MFD, EICAS, GPWS etc). Is there an answer to this?

Comment: This question is really hard to answer. I believe there are a few thousands processors and a few million other ICs on such a big thing. Also in the 80s micro processor and micro controllers are much more fragmented than they are now.

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/44349) doesn't mention the 737, but the answers do discuss the use of dissimilar hardware in redundant systems.

Comment: If it's using Collins Proline equipment (I think it does) it'll have early 80s microprocessors like the 8086, something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This wouldn't fit as a comment but doesn't get to the processor level of your question. The 737NG/Max has a large number of avionics systems as shown by [Airframer](http://www.airframer.com/aircraft_detail.html?model=B737#Flight%20and%20Data%20Management). Most of these have processors, some have multiple. In which of these are you interested?

[image: airframer.com]

Comment: I'm interested in the things that make/draw the EFIS stuff

Comment: OP, airframer is probably a really good place to start. Find in that list the exact model of the hardware you're considering. Then either try your luck at emailing the company directly or finding photos online and googling the chips. But I have a strong suspicion that all these will be ASICs (Application-specific integrated circuit) which might be not of use.