# Why do airplanes have rounded windows?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

Why are the windows of an airplane usually rounded at the edges?

[image]

Comment: `<style>border-radius:50px;</style>` That's about it for a programmer :P

Comment: That's HTML, probably [not used](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/what-programming-languages-are-used-for-equipment-onboard-aircraft) for airplanes :)

Comment: @Iceman that CSS is lexically incorrect.. :P

Comment: Airliner (Browser) Compatibility you know :)

Comment: Seems it's valid CSS: `window{color:white;border-radius:15cm}`

Comment: Perhaps the same reason why port holes are round in ships too?

Comment: the windows are round because the holes they make in the fuselage are round.

Comment: And the holes in the fuselage are round because [fitting a square peg in a round hole involves some retrofitting](http://history.nasa.gov/SP-350/ch-13-4.html) (top image; [also here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_13_LM_with_Mailbox_retouched.jpg)) that would look rather ugly on a commercial aircraft. Q.E.D.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues that code is invalid for U.S. Registered Aircraft. Welcome to the Imperial System. We've jot jackets.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

A pressurized fuselage needs rounded corners at all cut-outs to avoid the [accumulation of stress in corners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_concentration). If the corners were not rounded, the fuselage skin would need to be locally reinforced, or it would begin to crack there soon.

This was [learned the hard way](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/129764-tech-wrecks-lessons-from-some-of-the-biggest-hardware-screw-ups/3) by de Havilland, when their [Comet jet airliner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Comet) began to plunge out of the sky for unknown reasons. In one of the first major crash investigations in aviation history, the wreck of one was [lifted from the seafloor off Elba and re-assembled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOAC_Flight_781). Then it was learned that the pressurized cabin had burst from cracks emanating from the window corners.

[image: de Havilland Comet]

de Havilland Comet I. Note the square windows. The window which caused the destruction of G-ALYP was on top of the fuselage and cannot be seen in this picture. (Picture [source](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/129764-tech-wrecks-lessons-from-some-of-the-biggest-hardware-screw-ups/3))

[image: Color coded stress plot in a fuselage panel with window cutout]

Finite element simulation of corner stresses in a Comet fuselage skin.  Red denotes the highest stresses. (Picture [source](http://personal.egr.uri.edu/sadd/compclassroom/fea.html))

[Other aircraft companies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_Ju_49) had built pressurized cockpits twenty years earlier and did it right the first time …

Comment: A note on the Havilland: The cracks where detected not by reassembling the body but by building a full size container and using water to pressurize and depressurize: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Comet - [gvf](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/8904/gvf)

Comment: `If the corners were not rounded, the fuselage skin would need to be locally reinforced` .. How much re-inforcing would the 90 degree angled corners require? And would re-inforcing really solve the problem? Did anyone try it again?

Comment: @Firee: In theory, a sharp corner needs an infinite reinforcement. In reality, the reinforcement is stretched out but will still need to be substantial, and would need to have rounded corners itself, so the cutout becomes bigger. Stiffness in the straight part of the window frame would then be much lower, so it would attract less stress. Rounding the corners is simply the better approach.

Comment: Oh well, so much for triangular or hexagon or pentagon windows, in the name of design

Comment: @securitydude5: Actually, at least one pressurised jetliner (the [Caravelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sud_Aviation_Caravelle)) _did_ have triangular windows (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wing_fences_on_the_wing_of_a_Caravelle.jpg), for instance) - they just had to be _rounded_ triangles.

Comment: @Sean. Right. Oval windows were also used with success, see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vickers_Viscount#/media/File:British_Air_Ferries_Vickers_Viscount_Volpati-1.jpg)

Answer (score 45):

## Stress Distribution / Stress Concentration

The sharper you make a corner, the higher the stress will be. This is undesirable since it will increase the stress on the material and can promote fatigue which can lead to structural failure down the road.

You can avoid this problem by having a greater curve radius. This does not only apply to windows, but cabin/cargo doors as well on an aircraft.

[image: pic]

<sup>[Source](http://www.afgrow.net/applications/DTDHandbook/examples/page2_1.aspx)</sup>

When aircraft undergo conversions become freighters and add cargo doors, you will notice that they need to make the metal thicker around the door to help distribute stress, hence the area of unpainted metal:

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [transportarchive.org.uk](http://www.transportarchive.org.uk/aimages/G3412.jpg))</sub>

<sup>[Source](http://www.transportarchive.org.uk/aimages/G3412.jpg)</sup>

### Calculation

[Some material](http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/Su2012/EP/MaterialsforStudents/Aiello/Roark-Ch06.pdf) on this, although it make the simplification the stress is only in one direction rather than both as in real life. You can see how as $r$ becomes smaller the stress concentration $K_t$ goes up, raising the maximum stress ($\sigma_{max}$).

[image]

---

Footnote: There will have to be a little bit of 'play' between the window and fuselage for technical reasons, such as thermal and pressure expansion, making this type of arrangement necessary. If you could perfectly carry over the load in every direction to the window this would not be necessary.