# How did the B707 and DC-8 fight stress at the windows?

Tags: aircraft-design, windows

As it is evident from [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/why-do-airplanes-have-curved-windows)  question, 4 (or 3) de Havilland Comets crashed because of stress building around the rectangular windows. 
How did DC-8 and B707 fight this problem, especially as it is quite clear that both of them had rectangular windows as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the Boeing 707 and the DC-8 used radiused corners on all their windows to avoid the problems of stress concentration factors, plus additional pad ups around the openings in the skins for the Windows themselves.

[image]

([Source](http://s2.thisnext.com/media/largest_dimension/93AC2FF4.jpg))