# How to start to get in the field of aviation with degree of Computer Science?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, landing

I am a 3-year computer science student and really want to go into the field of aviation, but not able to figure out what should I do at this point of time so as to have a career in this field.

Comment: You could work for an avionics company pretty much everything is going the way of the computer in the cockpit. Some heavy hitters are [Garmin](https://explore.garmin.com/en-US/general-aviation/), [Rockwell Collins](http://www.rockwellcollins.com/) or products like [Foreflight](https://foreflight.com/)

Comment: Are there any special courses that I need to opt? Dave

Comment: [Avionics use all different languages](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/what-programming-languages-are-used-for-equipment-onboard-aircraft) but a solid understanding of micro-controllers/microprocessors can never hurt. A good understanding of how sensors (hardware) integrate into control systems would also be of use.

Comment: If at all possible, pursue a pilot licence.  In the US, it's almost free (whatever a CFI charges) to obtain a student pilot certificate, and the certificate does not expire.  When I was at this stage, I landed a technical job at a large aircraft manufacturer.  I was surprised how few of the employees were actually pilots.  It was a big advantage for me.

Comment: In my opinion having an aviation degree like aerospace engineering isn't a huge advantage, and for some roles they probably prefer someone with a strong software background. Most large avionics companies have separate control system design or aviation teams and a separate software team who handle lower-level architecture, compiling, building, testing, etc.  Evidence of your interest in and understanding of avionics could help though, including a course in aerodynamics, pilot training, or even things like 
a control systems or embedded programming class.